# C++ odd text behavior - random garbage text

Tags: c++, class

**SOLVED**

After I reinstalled my OS (2008 Server) I then noticed that there's something odd going on within my program.

Here's the link to part of the source http://phantomworksstudios.com/cpp/ss/sof-odd.h

Here's the code first:

#### custom-data.h

```
class INI_{

public:
const char* error;
stringstream CharToStr2;


Layout layout;      
Settings settings;

string file; 

int OpenFile(string open_file){
    CharToStr2.str("");
    ifstream SSMAIN_FILE_SETTINGS; 
    CharToStr2<<open_file;
    cout<<"CharToStr: "<<CharToStr2<<endl;
    cout<<"CharToStr.str(): "<<CharToStr2.str()<<endl; 
    cout<<"CharToStr.str.c_str(): "<<CharToStr2.str().c_str()<<endl;

    SSMAIN_FILE_SETTINGS.open(CharToStr2.str().c_str());
        if(!SSMAIN_FILE_SETTINGS){
        CharToStr2<<" is currupt or not found!. Loading default configuration!";
        cout<<"STRING1:"<<CharToStr2<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"STRING2:"<<CharToStr2.str()<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"STRING3:"<<CharToStr2.str().c_str()<<endl<<endl;
        error=CharToStr2.str().c_str(); 
        cout<<"ERROR:"<<error<<endl;   
        }
    cout <<"CLASS INI_: "<<SSMAIN_FILE_SETTINGS<<" : "<<file<<endl<<endl;
    }
};

INI_ SourceStudioConfiguration;
```

#### procedures.h

```
case WM_CREATE:  
SSMAIN_EXPLORERWINDOW_MENU=LoadMenu(SSMAIN_HINSTANCE,MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_EXPLORER_MENU));
    SourceStudioConfiguration.layout.cx=0;   
    User_Buffer=32767;
    OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),TOKEN_QUERY,&hToken);
    GetUserProfileDirectory(hToken,InfoBuf,&User_Buffer);
    User_Path=InfoBuf;
//      cout<<InfoBuf<<endl<<endl;
    CharToStr<<InfoBuf<<"\\Source Studio\\preference.ini";
    preference=CharToStr.str();
    cout<<User_Path<<" : "<<preference<<endl<<endl;
//       SourceStudioConfiguration.file=preference;
    SourceStudioConfiguration.OpenFile(preference);
    cout<<"CREATE:"<<SourceStudioConfiguration.error<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"Class File"<<SourceStudioConfiguration.file<<endl<<endl;
    hbmPWSBUTTON = (HBITMAP)LoadBitmap(hInst_PWSBUTTON, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IMG_PWS_BUTTON));
    cout<<"Load PWS Bitmap: "<<hbmPWSBUTTON<<endl;
    hbmPWSCommandOVERVIEW=(HBITMAP)LoadBitmap(hInst_PWSCOMMANDTB,  MAKENTRESOURCE(IMG_PWS_COMMAND_OVERVIEW));
    hbmPWSCommandDOCUMENT=(HBITMAP)LoadBitmap(hInst_PWSCOMMANDTB, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IMG_PWS_COMMAND_DOCUMENT));
    hbmPWSCommandNEWFILE=(HBITMAP)LoadBitmap(hInst_PWSCOMMANDTB, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IMG_PWS_COMMAND_NEWFILE));
    hbmPWSCommandCLOSE=(HBITMAP)LoadBitmap(hInst_PWSCOMMANDTB, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IMG_PWS_COMMAND_CLOSE));
    cout<<"CREATE:"<<SourceStudioConfiguration.error<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Load PWS Command Toolbar Bitmap: "<<hbmPWSCommandOVERVIEW<<endl;
    cout<<"CREATE 277:"<<SourceStudioConfiguration.error<<endl<<endl;
    SSMAIN_REBARWINDOW = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW|WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, REBARCLASSNAME,NULL,            WS_CHILD|WS_BORDER|RBS_VARHEIGHT|TBS_HORZ|RBS_BANDBORDERS|CCS_NODIVIDER|CCS_NOPARENTALIGN,0,0,0,0,hwnd, NULL, 0, 0);     
    SSMAIN_EXPLORERWINDOW=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT,"button",NULL, BS_GROUPBOX|WS_CHILD,0,79,150,SSMAIN_HEIGHT-157,hwnd, (HMENU)SSMAIN_EXPLORERWINDOW_MENU, SSMAIN_EXPLORERBAR_HINSTANCE, 0);     
    //SSMAIN_EXPLORERWINDOW_REBAR=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW|WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, REBARCLASSNAME, NULL, WS_CHILD|WS_BORDER|RBS_VARHEIGHT|TBS_HORZ|RBS_BANDBORDERS|CCS_NODIVIDER|CCS_NOPARENTALIGN, 0,0,0,0,SSMAIN_EXPLORERWINDOW,NULL,0,0);     
    SSMAIN_NAVIGATIONTOOLBAR=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW|WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, "TOOLBARWINDOW32", NULL, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS|TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS|TBSTYLE_FLAT|TBSTYLE_ALTDRAG|TBSTYLE_LIST|CCS_NODIVIDER|CCS_NOPARENTALIGN|CCS_ADJUSTABLE|CCS_NORESIZE, 0, 0, 0, 0,SSMAIN_REBARWINDOW, (HMENU)IDC_NAVIGATIONTOOLBAR, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    SSMAIN_EXPLORERWINDOW_OVERVIEW=CreateWindowEx(0,"button", NULL,BS_BITMAP|BS_USERBUTTON|BS_TEXT|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, 4, 12, 18, 18,SSMAIN_EXPLORERWINDOW, (HMENU)IDC_EXPLORERWINDOW_REBAR_COMMANDBAR, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    SSMAIN_EXPLORERWINDOW_DOCUMENT=CreateWindowEx(0, "button",NULL,BS_BITMAP|BS_USERBUTTON|BS_TEXT|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, 24, 12, 18, 18,SSMAIN_EXPLORERWINDOW, (HMENU)IDC_EXPLORERWINDOW_REBAR_COMMANDBAR, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    SSMAIN_EXPLORERWINDOW_NEWFILE=CreateWindowEx(0,"button",NULL, BS_BITMAP|BS_USERBUTTON|BS_TEXT|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, 44, 12, 18, 18,SSMAIN_EXPLORERWINDOW, (HMENU)IDC_EXPLORERWINDOW_REBAR_COMMANDBAR, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    SSMAIN_EXPLORERWINDOW_CLOSE=CreateWindowEx(0,"button",NULL, BS_BITMAP|BS_USERBUTTON|BS_TEXT|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, 62, 12, 18, 18,SSMAIN_EXPLORERWINDOW, (HMENU)IDC_EXPLORERWINDOW_REBAR_COMMANDBAR, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    //SSMAIN_PARENTCONTAINER=CreateWindow("SYSTABCONTROL32","", WS_EX_COMPOSITED|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,100,100,0,0,hwnd,(HMENU)ID_PARENTCONTAINER,SSMAIN_PARENTCONTAINER_HINSTANCE, NULL);                  
    SSMAIN_STATIC_RTF_CONTAINER=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT|WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "static","",WS_CHILD,0,0,0,0,hwnd,(HMENU)IDC_STATIC_RTF_CONTAINER,0,0);
    SSMAIN_STATIC_RTFCONTROL_PARENT_HSCROLL=CreateWindow("SCROLLBAR","", WS_EX_COMPOSITED|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|SBS_BOTTOMALIGN,100,100,20,20,SSMAIN_STATIC_RTF_CONTAINER,(HMENU)IDC_STATIC_RTFCONTROL_PARENT_HSCROLL,SSMAIN_PARENTCONTAINER_HINSTANCE,NULL);        

    SSMAIN_LISTBOXRTFCOUNT= CreateWindowEx(0,"LISTBOX",NULL, WS_CHILD|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS|ECO_AUTOVSCROLL|LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT|LBS_NOTIFY|WS_VISIBLE|WS_GROUP, 0,0,0,0,SSMAIN_STATIC_RTF_CONTAINER,(HMENU)IDC_LISTBOXRTFCOUNT,NULL,NULL);             

    SSMAIN_RTFCONTROL=CreateWindow("RICHEDIT","text", WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOHSCROLL|WS_VSCROLL|WS_HSCROLL|WS_GROUP, 0,0,0,0,SSMAIN_STATIC_RTF_CONTAINER,(HMENU)IDC_RTFCONTROL,SSMAIN_RTFCONTROL_HINSTANCE,0);

    SSMAIN_TOOLBAR=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW|WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, "TOOLBARWINDOW32", NULL, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS|TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS|TBSTYLE_FLAT|TBSTYLE_ALTDRAG|TBSTYLE_LIST|CCS_NODIVIDER|CCS_NOPARENTALIGN|CCS_ADJUSTABLE|CCS_NORESIZE, 0, 0, 0, 0,hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_TOOLBAR, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    SSMAIN_STATUSBAR = CreateWindow("MSCTLS_STATUSBAR32", "", WS_EX_COMPOSITED|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 0, 0, hwnd, NULL, 0, NULL);                          

    cout<<"CREATE 300:"<<SourceStudioConfiguration.error<<endl<<endl;   SendMessage(SSMAIN_STATUSBAR,SB_SETPARTS,(WPARAM)3,(LPARAM)&panes);
    SSMAIN_TOOLBARSYNTAX = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW|WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, "TOOLBARWINDOW32", NULL, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS|TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS|TBSTYLE_FLAT|TBSTYLE_ALTDRAG|TBSTYLE_LIST|CCS_NODIVIDER|CCS_NOPARENTALIGN|CCS_ADJUSTABLE|CCS_NORESIZE, 0, 0, 0, 0,SSMAIN_REBARWINDOW, (HMENU)IDC_TOOLBARSYNTAX, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    SSMAIN_PWSBUTTON = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, "static", NULL, SS_BITMAP|TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS|SS_NOTIFY|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE, 50, 50, 32, 32, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_PWSBUTTON, 0, 0);     
                                                                                                         SSMAIN_TOOLTIP = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLTIPS_CLASS, 0, WS_POPUP|TTS_ALWAYSTIP, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, hwnd, 0, SSMAIN_HINSTANCE, 0);
```

Now for some reason after `SSMAIN_RTFCONTROL=CreateWindow("RICHEDIT","...` when I display `cout<<"CREATE 300:"<<SourceStudioConfiguration.error<<endl<<endl;`   the text is all random text. Now if I used the same thing before `SSMAIN_RTFCONTROL=CreateWindow("RICHEDIT","...` it will display correctly like it should.

My question is why is it doing that?

Also if I ignore `SSMAIN_RTFCONTROL=CreateWindow("RICHEDIT","...`  as  comment it will work like it should but then after some more lines on the cmd window it will display as random text again.

Is there something going on that I don't see?  Like too much info going on where it start to mess with the error space and maybe setting something within it and it shouldn't?

Also as far as I can remember I didn't have this problem before I reinstalled my os.

Thanks and I'm really confused about this and if you need anymore info let me know and I'll post them

Also guys I tried to format the code by applying spaces like it said, but at times it doesn't allow any spaces in front of the line and other times it does so I don't know what's up with that.

Comment: Could you fix your code formatting?  See the editing help for details on how to mark code so that indentation and line breaks won't be lost, and so `<` won't be read as an HTML tag opener (something is clearly missing around `cout<<"CREATE 300;"<`).

Comment: You need to STOP SHOUTING in your code (it makes it unreadable), and you need to use spaces after commas (which avoids the problems with sometimes it allows spaces and sometimes it doesn't).  I've sort of fixed it up, but I decline to spend any energy reading the inscrutably unreadable.  I guess I must be lucky; I've never had to read such code before.  You need to find a way to reduce the apparent complexity and repetition in the code. I note there is no error checking; I hope the called functions throw exceptions on failure. Your problem may well be something failing and you haven't noticed.

Comment: Can I see where you operate with `error`, especially the places where you assign it to some value.

Comment: Well i'm lost when you said stop shouting?, if your talking about me using SSMAIN_... I do that for a reason.  Also in my programming everytime after a case statement or If statement I indent my code ahead as that make it more readable. Also I didn't know or think about the space after the comma so I'll will start to do that.   Now for the error part that is used within a class for handling ini files or other setting files. If the file doesn't exist or there is a problem the error from the class will be set and then from there will be set to the status bar.  Also thanks Jonathan for the help.

Comment: ok guys here's the solution even though I don't know why if that makes any sense...
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/69379/ (Last Post)
refer to this url as I can't post the whole solution here.  Also i'm going to work on the shouting part and start adding spaces after commas. I'm still getting a grasp on c++ here, working with php helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok guys here's the solution even though I don't know why if that makes any sense...

```
class INI_{    

    public:
    const char* error;
    stringstream CharToStr2;
    string errordesc;
    Layout layout;      
    Settings settings;  
    string file; 

    int OpenFile(string open_file){
    CharToStr2.str("");
    ifstream SSMAIN_FILE_SETTINGS; 
    CharToStr2<<open_file;
    cout<<"CharToStr: "<<CharToStr2<<endl;
    cout<<"CharToStr.str(): "<<CharToStr2.str()<<endl; 
    cout<<"CharToStr.str.c_str(): "<<CharToStr2.str().c_str()<<endl;

    SSMAIN_FILE_SETTINGS.open(CharToStr2.str().c_str());
    if(!SSMAIN_FILE_SETTINGS){
        CharToStr2<<" is currupt or not found!. Loading default configuration!";
        cout<<"STRING1:"<<CharToStr2<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"STRING2:"<<CharToStr2.str()<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"STRING3:"<<CharToStr2.str().c_str()<<endl<<endl;
        errordesc=CharToStr2.str();
        error=errordesc.c_str(); 
        cout<<"ERROR:"<<error<<endl;   
    }
    cout <<"CLASS INI_: "<<SSMAIN_FILE_SETTINGS<<" : "<<file<<endl<<endl;
}
};
```

Noticed that I added a variable string errordesc and assigned the source stream to that, then assigned errordesc to error